Cannot find npm module
After installing node js the npm is not installed on my PC When I type node-v in the terminal it shows the version of nodejs but when I type npm --v it shows the following error :
PS C:\Users\sarath> npm --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sarath\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.12.2
I checked for many videos on YouTube but everyone was saying to reinstall. It is not even working after re-installing

The problem is, there could be dozens of things wrong with your system. Things that could help:   use NVM to install node versions OR check your PATH variables of your system perhaps you have multiple NODE processes interfering OR you could try to use the full name of the executable e.g. nvm.cmd AND I would personally avoid the "powershell terminal" but use the classic one. I would always run it as administer. AND I would suggest detecting and removing all broken NPM and NODE versions before trying to reinstall it. To make sure they are out of your PATH variable scope.

what could also help: you can detect the location of windows processes with the WHERE CLI command. e.g. WHERE npm should show you where NPM is installed. That can help you to verify that all node/npm versions are removed before reinstalling any of them.
